# creating dynamic dependent drop down from database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

i have two drop downs from the mysql database in which both are interdependent. what i need is when i select an area from the first drop down, the second drop down as to filter accordingly matching the area from the first drop down. can anyone help me out. [The first drop down is area and the second drop down is zone ].kindly help me out with the changes in this two files. thanks in advance.

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
```

## Create your models here.

> views.py

def dashboard_view(request):
    import mysql.connector

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                    database='lab_view',
                    user='root',
                    password='inbabtslabuser'
                    )
sql_select_Query ="""select DISTINCT Area from main_labview;"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchall()

sql_select_Query ="""select DISTINCT Zone from main_labview;"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records1 = cursor.fetchall()

sql_select_Query ="""select DISTINCT Rack from main_labview;"""
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records2 = cursor.fetchall()
a_list=[]
z_list=[]
r_list=[]
for row in records2:
    r_list.append(row[0])
for row in records:
    a_list.append(row[0])

for row in records1:
    z_list.append(row[0])    
print("\n\n###########################################\nFrom Database:\nAreas: ", a_list)
print("Zones: ",z_list)
print("###########################################\n\n")

context={'Area':a_list, 'Zones':z_list, 'Racks':r_list}

return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html', context)
```

> .html

```
<form action="/db2/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
<strong><font color="red">Area:</font></strong>
<select id="Area_ID" name="Area" >
<option value="None" selected>Select Area</option>
{% for a in Area %}
    <option value="{{ a }}">{{ a }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>


      <br><br>
<strong><font color="red" >Zone:</font></strong>
<select id="Zone_ID" name="Zone" >
<option value="None" selected>Select Zone</option>
{% for z in Zones %}
    <option value="{{ z }}">{{ z }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>





        <br> </br>
        <button type="submit" name="try" onClick="location.href='{% url 'db2' %}';" value='submits'>Find Racks</button><br>

        </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your model.py code snippet

Comment: hello i have shared my models.py which i havent done anything in that snippet.kindly look into it thank u. @ShahidTariq

Comment: @andarsh You have nothing in your models.py file. How do you create the models for your app

Comment: i'm just fetching the data from the query from mysql database , and creating a list and pushing that list of data into the html page. do i really have to create models.py for that. if yes can u please guide me,i'm very new to django ! thank you . @ShahidTariq

Comment: @andarsh Django provides the best support to deal with backend databases by ORM. You just need to create tables with Django models and than do ORM queries to create update and delete operations. check it out here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#module-django.db.models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is nothing in your models.py file. I believe you are doing it
>   totally the wrong way. You should create tables by Django models not directly by running create table commands in MYSQL shell, like:

```
from django.db import models

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Zone(models.Model):
    Area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rack(models.Model):
    Zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

> Moreover, doing a direct MySQL connection is not a good practice in
>   Django as Django automatically handles database connections see here:
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#module-django.db.models
>
> On the top of everything that you are trying to do is best exampled in
>   here:
>   https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html you can follow this blog and try to interdependent dropdowns in Django